# Why is this deep Q agent constantly learning just one action?

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, open-ai, pytorch, gym

I'm trying to implement deep q learning in the OpenAI's gym "Taxi-v3" environment. But my agent only learns to do one action in every state. What am I doing wrong? Here is the [Github repository with the code](https://github.com/OleVoss/DeepTaxi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought about my input-layer. I had the 500 states one hot encoded. So 499 of every input node would be 0. And 0 is very bad in an neural network. I tried the same code with the "CardPole-v0" and it worked.

So think about your input guys